# Problem while debugging c# code in Visual studio code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have this method

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var numbers = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4};
}
public static int GetSmallest(List<int> list)
{
    var min = list[0];
    for (var i = 1; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] > min)
        min = list[i];
    }
    return min;
}
```

When changing the condition to list[I] < min while in debug mode the min variable in the watch window is 2 but it is supposed to be 1. Any idea why changing code doesn't affect anything until I run the program again?
[Video showing problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMQLo.jpg)

Comment: VSCode doesn't support Edit and Continue: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/490

Comment: This is normal... you need to rebuild project if you want see changes

Comment: Thank you for the answers